# Devexpress Gridview populate just a 100 row keeps freezing

Tags: vb.net

I have WinForm .Net 4 project using Devexpress gridview

I want to populate this gridview using data from my model which look like this:

```
Public Class CustomerModel

    Public Property IDCustomer As Integer
    Public Property CodeCustomer As String
    Public Property NameCustomer As String
    .....
End Class
```

I have populate the model just fine after fetching it from returned JSON on my web
at this point, no freeze happen, even with more than 1000 data is fetched

but when I want to populate the grid like this:

```
  Dim Table1 As DataTable
  Dim dataList As List(Of CustomerModel) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of CustomerModel))(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getFilter("data_list")))


For Each dataItem As CustomerModel In result
    Dim Row1 As DataRow = Table1.NewRow()

    With dataItem
        Row1.Item("IDCustomer") = .IDCustomer
        ...
        ...

    end with
 Next

dgvTabel.DataSource = Table1
```

then the app keep freezing, even with just only 100 data fetched

I have also tried to using background worker but the freeze still happening. I though Devexpress Gridview can handle thousand data almost instantly to gridview. how to do that in my case?

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Where does this "freeze" occur? Is it on the line where you set the `DataSource` of the grid? If not then what does the grid have to do with the issue? You need to be much more precise about the specific issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes it immediately freezes like 4 to 6 sec when I set the datasource. the app does not freeze even when I loop dataItem. only when set Datasource this is happening